# Close active accordion item

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I found this sweet accordion menu and I want to modify it a little bit. I want to add a close function, so if I click on the `h2` that's active it will slide up and close. How can I achieve that?

```
$(function() {
    $('#accordion .content').hide();
    $('#accordion h2:first').addClass('active').next().slideDown('slow');
    $('#accordion h2').click(function() {
        if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
            $('#accordion h2').removeClass('active').next().slideUp('slow');
            $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/CzE3q/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check to see if the item you clicked on already has the `active` class. Try this:

```
$('#accordion .content').hide();
$('#accordion h2:first').addClass('active').next().slideDown('slow');

$('#accordion h2').click(function () {
    var openPanel = !$(this).hasClass('active')
    $('#accordion h2').removeClass('active').next().slideUp('slow');
    openPanel && $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown('slow');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CzE3q/718/)

Comment: `.stop()` will also be helpful for OP .

Comment: Damn your fast. Works like a charm :) @Rory McCrossan

Comment: I like the inclusion of `openPanel`, nice touch.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `else` block to the `click` event handler that closes the pane if it is not hidden.

```
$(function() {
    $('#accordion .content').hide();
    $('#accordion h2:first').addClass('active').next().slideDown('slow');
    $('#accordion h2').click(function() {
        if($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
            $('#accordion h2').removeClass('active').next().slideUp('slow');
            $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown('slow');
        }else{
            $('#accordion h2').removeClass('active').next().slideUp('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/CzE3q/720/